# Highcharts show max., min., and average for each serie in legend

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm having some charts where it would be nice to show **minimum**, **maximum** and **average** values for each serie separately. In the legend is not a "must", but it would be very nice. Another solution might be to show the min, max and actual value right in the chart (at the point), that would also be a very nice solution. Number of series varies from 1-4 at the moment, in different charts.

Actual value (or the latest value actually) is already in the legend.

*In addition I want these values to be updated "at all times", both at first load and when changing zoom. When changing zoom it should be based on the selection, so when selecting "1 m" it must show the values for the last month and so on.*

http://jsfiddle.net/dg4wpg0t/1/

Any help is appreciated :)

One example of final result (red text):
[image: Final result]

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

chart: {
    zoomType: 'x'
},

legend: {
    enabled: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
        var lastVal = this.yData[this.yData.length - 1];
        return this.name + '<br>' + 'Now: ' + lastVal + ' °C';
        }
},

  series: [{
    name: 'Outside',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 01), 0.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 06), -1.4],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 11), -2.6],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 16), 11.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 21), -11.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 26), 3.7],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 01), 4.9],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 06), 8.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 11), 0.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 16), -1.4],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 21), -2.6],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 26), -5.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 01), -8.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 06), 3.7],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 11), 4.9],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 16), 5.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 21), 0.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 26), -1.4],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 01), -2.6],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 06), -5.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 11), -8.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 16), 11.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 21), -11.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 26), 5.2]
        ]
    }, {
    name: 'Inside',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 01), 17.8],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 06), 27.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 11), 17.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 16), 21.7],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 21), 25.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 26), 24.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 01), 22.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 06), 24.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 11), 19.8],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 16), 20.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 21), 26.5],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 26), 21.7],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 01), 25.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 06), 24.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 11), 22.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 16), 24.1],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 21), 19.8],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 03, 26), 20.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 01), 24.5],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 06), 21.7],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 11), 27.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 16), 17.2],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 21), 22.3],
        [Date.UTC(2016, 04, 26), 24.1]
        ]
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the calculations on chart start (load event) and on [redraw event](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.redraw). You can disable data grouping - for the amount of data you have, data grouping is not necessary - disabling it simplifies data grabbing.

1. Filter visible points
2. Make statistics for them
3. Replace the text inside the legend

The function:

```
function calculateStatistics() {
      this.series.slice(0, 2).forEach(series => { // take only two first series, the last is for the navigator
        const data = series.data.filter(point => point.isInside).map(point => point.y); // grab only points within the visible range

        // calculate statistics for visible points
        const statistics = [
          data[data.length - 1],
          Math.max.apply(null, data),
          Math.min.apply(null, data),
          (data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / data.length).toFixed(1)
        ];

        const legendItem = series.legendItem;
        let i = -1;
        // construct the legend string
        const text = legendItem.textStr.replace(/-?\d+\.\d/g, () => statistics[++i]);

        // set the constructed text for the legend
        legendItem.attr({
          text: text
        });
      });
    }
```

And set the function on the events

```
chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
      load: calculateStatistics,
      redraw: calculateStatistics
    }
},
```

Styling text can be done in the [legend.labelFormatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/legend.labelFormatter)

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/jfLtodf9/

[image: Custom legend]

Comment: Thanks! In the end I need to have data gruoping actually, this is just an simple chart example, but let's not focus on that for now... One problem still, if a value without decimals is put in the Legend the value will freeze and not get updated anymore, probably because textStr.replace can not find the "."...? Any good solution for this? :) I would also like to have the "Now" values (actual values) as the most recent value of the serie, not filtered by selection. Min, max and average on the other hand is OK. http://jsfiddle.net/jfLtodf9/1/

Comment: You need to adjust the regex I use - it will not work for every representation of the number - if you have data in weird format, maybe it is better to build a whole new string instead of replacing the one which exists. To access non filtered data, use series.data - http://jsfiddle.net/wd0waL0s/

Comment: Not there yet.. I added some more data just for testing, and when I zoom in and change selection values are not updating as they should. http://jsfiddle.net/wd0waL0s/3/

Comment: You can build a new string instead of replacing the existing one. http://jsfiddle.net/wd0waL0s/5/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now I'm trying to add data labels in my chart at the maximum and minimum values based on the function you made for me :) I tried with some manually entered values (at event afterSetExtremes), so this is basically what I want in the end but updated at redraw and load just like the legend. Maybe chart update isn't the way to go. http://jsfiddle.net/wd0waL0s/7/

Comment: I would render custom labels and reposition them on redraw/afterSetExtremes - updating chart might not be very efficient in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/3f7gm784/ If I solve your problem, accept my answer. If you have another problem/question, you should create a new topic on stack overflow.